# Can we have the same Instagram filter effects using only OpenGL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am trying to do something like Instagram but without using the GPUImage framework.
I use only OpenGL 2.0 and shaders.At the beginning,I take  one shader  and  textures that Instagram uses  and employ them in my project.I didn't get the same result and the same filter effect.I don't understand why there is a difference.GPUImage is based on OpenGL too.Is there something particular in Instagram and the GPUImage framework?

Comment: Well yes you can do that with GLSL (Shaders) like you said, and you're probably calculating something wrong when applying the shader. Could you please actually show the Shader code that you've made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason at all you can't reimplement the same sorts of filters seen in Instagram yourself using OpenGL. It's just a "simple matter" of creating some textures and developing some shaders that do the trick. You might find that you can experiment in Photoshop or using the GLShader tool to prototype your algorithms before actually cutting code. This will probably save some time.

Apparently the filters took months of tweaking to get just the right "look", so don't expect to recreate it overnight. I remember reading an article on the history and inception of Instagram, which makes interesting reading.

After about a minute of searching, I found this Quora thread where Kevin Systrom himself weighs in, while the top commenter has posted a reverse-engineered description of some of the methods:

- [Quora discussion on Instagram filters](http://www.quora.com/Instagram/How-does-Instagram-develop-their-filters)

Note that his github repo has been taken down, as he foolishly extracted textures from the app itself and reposted them online. Obviously this is a copyright violation, so don't do this!  I suggest you derive inspiration from Instagram, but develop your own unique filters from scratch.

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do exactly.I start with Instagram to see how it works after that I develop my own filters from scratch.But when I try the shaders of Instagram I didn't have the same effects.I thought it's strange because I am not using the framework.

Comment: Whether or not you use the GPUImage framework, there are still many other factors that can affect the results. Preprocessing in the CPU before the shaders are run, uniform parameters, and all sorts of things. Anyway, sorry, but we can't help you with code lifted from someone else's product. There are enough books and articles around to create your own filters without having to do this. Start with a simple high contrast B&W filter, and add some grain. Then try a sepia tone filter, and work up to the more complex effects.

Comment: Yes... I start from the scratch and I am developing my own filters.Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Your answer is quite enlightening .